# I've Tried - Single Page html with php vs google formscontact form

Tags: php, html, forms

I was ask by a client to use link their contact form to a google doc. I have a video that shows step by step what i did but when i am submitting the form there is a redirect to a page that is being worked on and there is no response sent to the form file. I will post the code for the code.:

```html
<div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12 forma">
<!--<form id="form" action="MWSContact.php" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">-->
                      <!--
                       <fieldset>
                        <input type="text" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 name" name='name' placeholder='Name *'/>
                        <input type="text" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 Email" name='Email' placeholder='Email *'/>
                        <input type="text" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 Subject" name='Subject' placeholder='Subject'/>
                        <textarea type="text" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 Message" name='Message' placeholder='Message *'></textarea>
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="cBtn col-xs-12">
        <fieldset>
            <input class="send" type="submit" value="Send" />
            <input class="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" />
        </fieldset>
                      </div>  -->
      <!--  </form>-->
                </div>
```

```html
<?
if (isset($_POST['email'])){

//Here is the email to info
$emial_to = 'email';
$email_subject = "MWS Contact";
$email_from = "Client";
//Error Code
function died ($error){
echo "We are sorry, but there were error (s) in your submitted form.";
echo "These errors appear below.<br/><br/>";

echo $error. "<br/><br/>";
echo "Please check your information again.<br/>";
die();
}
//Validation
if (!isset($_POST['name']) ||
!isset($_POST['email']) ||
!isset($_POST['message']) ||
!isset($_POST['subject'])){
died ('We are sorry but there appears to be a probem with your form submitted.');
}
//values
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message= $_POST['message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
//error messages
$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

if (!preg_match($email_exp, $email)){
    $error_message .= 'The Email address you entered does not appear to be valid. <br/>';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z.'-]+$/";
    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $name)){
        $error_message .= 'The name you endtered does not appear to be valid. <br/>';
    }
    if (strlen($message) <2){
        $error_message .= 'The comment you entered does not appear to be valid.<br/>';
    }
    if (strlen($email_message) >0){
        died($error_message);
    }
    //Sanitize
    $email_message = "Form Details Below\n\n";

    function clean_string($string){
        $bad = array("content-type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
        return str_replace($bad," ", $string);
    }
        $email_message .="Name:" . clean_string($name) . "\n";
        $email_message .="Email:" . clean_string($email) . "\n";
        $email_message .="Subject:" . clean_string($subject) . "\n";
        $email_message .="Message:" . clean_string($message) . "\n";
"\n";
    //headers
    $headers = 'From: ' .$email_From . "\r\n". 'Reply-To:' . $email. "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' .phpversion();
        @mail ($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

}
?>
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in contact with you shortly.
```

[google form](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58eY-XzECOg)

Comment: `Email` and `email` are two different animals altogether, check all your inputs and POST arrays. Error reporting is your friend http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - and remove the `@` symbol, it's an error suppressor.

Comment: Plus, your form's code is commented out, *why?*

Comment: Because I was testing out the google form method when I took the code from this, but would it be different to use email or Email with a gmail?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your (PHP) file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, you are not connecting to anything Google in any way in the shown code.

Comment: This will only work once it is pushed out to the server right, Been swamped and contact forms don't usual give me this problem

Comment: I've posted an answer below to better illustrate.

Comment: this is the google code <iframe class="img-responsive picsGall" src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/19oQIYIKBXZYq1mSMLhohcvzIyhYdjHrmfUFfASMsP3k/viewform?embedded=true" width="5000" height="5000" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>

Comment: @AnthonyCook I've made quite a few edits since I first posted my answer below and found a few other things wrong, so in case you may have seen it, please reload my answer and including having a look at my **Footnotes**

Comment: At least, you have tried!

Comment: @Eric The Lord as my witness, yes... I have (tried) ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Look at the lettercase for all your POST arrays for your assignments and conditional statements:

- `$_POST['name']`
- `$_POST['email']`
- `$_POST['message']`
- `$_POST['subject']`

then in your form

```
<input type="text" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 name" name='name' placeholder='Name *'/>
<input type="text" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 Email" name='Email' placeholder='Email *'/>
<input type="text" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 Subject" name='Subject' placeholder='Subject'/>
<textarea type="text" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 Message" name='Message' placeholder='Message *'></textarea>
```

Lettercase must match. You have `email` in `$_POST['email']` and then `name='Email'` for your input.

Nothing inside the `if (isset($_POST['email'])){...}` conditional statement will fire up for that reason, including all other POST arrays which will not populate.

- Same thing for all others. POST arrays/variables are case-sensitive.

So change them all to match `name='email'` and do the rest for the others.

- **Also, remove** `enctype="text/plain"` from the form tags, that will make your form fail also;
  ***this is very important***.
- Remember to remove the `<!--` and `-->` from your code. Those are HTML comments and nothing will show up on your screen, nor executed.
- Make sure that short open tags are enabled. Otherwise, you will need to change `<?` to `<?php`.
- Remove the `@` for `@mail`, it's an error suppressor.

---

Error reporting would have signaled "Undefined index Email...." and others while having it enabled.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

**Footnotes:**

It doesn't seem like you're doing anything with `$subject` and there is nothing assigned for `$email_to` in regards to where it's being emailed to. You will need to modify your code as to what it should be.

- `$email_to = "email@example.com";` needs to be added in your code, replacing it with your email address.

Edit:

You have `$emial_to = 'email';` that's a typo. See above code.

`$email_From` and `$email_from = "Client";` more typos.

You should be using `$email` instead, and from `$email = $_POST['email'];`

- [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) expects a `From:` to be an email and not a name.

`$headers = 'From: ' .$email_From` <= which should be `$email`.

*...the edits seem to be next to endless.*

Please go over your entire code and make sure that everything matches, no typos, letter-case issues. etc.

- I believe I've given you more than enough to get you started.

Comment: For the purpose of this post I had taken out the my email to make sure there was no unneed emails to make sure testing this is not interrupted

Comment: @AnthonyCook I've done what I could to go over your entire code. There are many syntax errors, typos etc. and I've made quite a few edits since. You'll need to go over your entire code and my answer, in order to make sure that everything matches. I did what I could, good luck.

Comment: yeah to clarify this is the errors that i got from the report btw Notice: Undefined variable: email_message in Hosting\12066284\html\mernwebservice\MWScontact.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined variable: email_From in Hosting\12066284\html\mernwebservice\MWScontact.php on line 62
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in contact with you shortly.

Comment: @AnthonyCook notice these `$email_message .=` where you have `$email_message .="Name:" . clean_string($name) . "\n";` etc., those should be `$error_message .=`

Comment: thank you, been working all over the place so didn't notice the typos and now i just have to get this fixed which i believe i have the information saved for this 
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 503 need RCPT before DATA in D:\Hosting\12066284\html\mernwebservice\MWScontact.php on line 63
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in contact with you shortly.